# love2d: How to change value in map table?

Tags: loops, dictionary, lua, love2d

Recently I started learning love2d and now I am making a collision map in tiles.

I want to change only index where some random sized boxes generated in the map table by loop. But somehow I can't get them changed correctly. I am quite a beginner and have no clear understang how tables work.. Could someone give me correct way to do it?
currently I set mapsize width 480, height 320, and tilesize is 16.

```
function generateBoxes()
    for i=1,5 do
        local x=math.random (0, mapsizex*tilesize)
        local y=math.random (0, mapsizey*tilesize)
        local width=math.random(1,6)
        local height=math.random(1,4)
        
        ChangeMap(math.floor(x/tilesize),math.floor(y/tilesize),width,height,1)
    end
    PrintMap()
end


function MakeNewMap()
    for row = 1,mapsizey do
        map[row] = {}
        for column = 1,mapsizex do
            map[row][column]= 0
        end
    end
end

function ChangeMap(x,y,w,h,num)
    print("x"..x.." y"..y.." w"..w.." h"..h)
    
    for i=y, h+1 do
        for j=x,w do 
            map[i][j]=num
        end
    end
    
end

function PrintMap()
    for i = 1, #map do
        local s = ''
        for j= 1, #map[i] do
            s = (s .. ' ' .. map[i][j])
        end
        print(s)
    end
end
```

Sorry my english is probably strange, I wanted it to work as it first makes a map table like this

```
map={ 
{0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0},
 }
```

and then I want to swap some parts to 1 like this for example,

```
map={ 
{0,0,0,0,0},
{0,1,1,0,0},
{0,1,1,0,0}, 
}
```

Comment: Can you be more detailed on what is going wrong? and what the desired result should be?

Comment: Sorry my english is probably strange, I wanted it to work as
 it first makes a map table like 

map={
{0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0},
}

and then I want to swap some parts to 1 like this for example,
```
map={
{0,0,0,0,0},
{0,1,1,0,0},
{0,1,1,0,0},
}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html

```lua
for var=exp1,exp2,exp3 do
   something
end
```

> That loop will execute something for each value of var from exp1 to exp2, using exp3 as the step to increment var. This third expression is optional; when absent, Lua assumes one as the step value

You however used `for i=y, h do` and misused `exp2` as the number of loops. Change it to `for i=y, y+h do`

Unrelated but important: You never check the bounds in ChangeMap, which produces unexpected results when the box exceeds the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

@Luke100000, Thank you for the explanation, I was trying also another way and ended now like this.And this looks working ok..

```
    for i=0, h-1 do
        for j=0,w-1 do
            if  (i+y)>0 and (j+x)>0 and (i+y)<=mapsizey and (j+x)<=mapsizex  then
                map[i+y][j+x]=num
            end
        end
   end
```

I attach the whole sample code to test.

```html
function love.load()
    math.randomseed (os.clock ())
    screensizex=love.graphics.getWidth()
    screensizey=love.graphics.getHeight()
    tilesize=16
    map={}
    mapsizex = screensizex/tilesize     --30 tiles
    mapsizey = screensizey/tilesize     --20tiles
    MakeNewMap()
    --generateBoxes()
end

function love.update(dt)

end






function generateBoxes()
     
     for i=1,5 do
            local x=math.random (0, mapsizex*tilesize)
            local y=math.random (0, mapsizey*tilesize)
            local width=math.random(1,6)
            local height=math.random(1,4)
            
            ChangeMap(math.floor(x/tilesize),math.floor(y/tilesize),width,height,1)
    end
    --PrintMap()
end


function MakeNewMap()
    for row = 1,mapsizey do
        map[row] = {}
        for column = 1,mapsizex do
            map[row][column]= 0
        end
    end
end

function ChangeMap(x,y,w,h,num)
    print("x"..x.." y"..y.." w"..w.." h"..h)

    for i=0, h-1 do
        for j=0,w-1 do
            if  (i+y)>0 and (j+x)>0 and (i+y)<=mapsizey and (j+x)<=mapsizex  then
                map[i+y][j+x]=num
            end
        end
   end

end

function PrintMap()
    for i = 1, #map do
        --print("#map:"..#map)
        local s = ""
        for j= 1, #map[i] do
            s = (s .. " " .. map[i][j])
        end
        print(s)
    end
    print(" ")
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    if key=="space" then
        PrintMap()
    end
    if key=="g" then
        generateBoxes()
        PrintMap()
    end
    if key=="c" then
        ChangeMap(3,2,3,2,1)
    end
    if key=="n" then
        MakeNewMap()
    end
    
end
```

Comment: That's also a solution, but notices that you need far more + operations and I can skip the inner conditions altogether using math.min/max directly on the loop range.

Comment: I am quite newbie.. I didn't know even what math.min/max are.
Would you tell me more about your way with math.min/max?

Comment: To get rid of the + you can directly iterate over the absolute positions rather than the relative ones: `for i=y, y+h-1 do`. Then in the body of the loop, you can directly use `i`.

Comment: Now we remove the inner condition: when is it invalid? When its smaller than 0 or larger than `mapsize - 1`. So we have to make sure the loop doesn't even consider those values. This can be done by using min/max, e.g. `math.max(0, x)` prevents x from every becoming negative, because 0 is larger than any negative x. Same with `math.min(mapsizex - 1, x)`, cant get larger than `mapsizex - 1`. The result would be `for i = math.max(0, y), math.min(mapsizey - 1, y + h - 1) do`. Doesn't matter how big the box is, even if it would exceed the mapsize completely, the values are within the valid range.

Comment: And here are the definitions of the math functions: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.7

Comment: Thanks for the well explaination. I could see thats clever way to do with min/max! Meanwhile I could change it as you said it can directly iterate over the absolute positions rather than the relative ones. My code works at the moment ok but I will try with math.min/max later.